# How to get list of registered views in prism with MEF

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, prism, mef

Or a list of registered parts ?

tried

```
[Import]
CompositionContainer container;
```

but it failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your Bootstrapper is exporting the CompositionContainer.

Starting with Prism's ModularityWithMef sample, I added the following to `QuickStartBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper`

```
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        this.Container.ComposeExportedValue<CompositionContainer>(this.Container);
    }
```

Then I was able to access the CompositionContainer from other modules.

Also try using `[Import(AllowDefault = true, AllowRecomposition = true)]` to get out of dependencies.

Comment: [Import(AllowDefault = true, AllowRecomposition = true)] didn't work, since it,s contained in prism cant use batch.AddExportedValue(_container);
etc

Comment: Updated answer for Prism specifics